# Redirect from node server to nginx server

Tags: node.js, nginx, httpserver

I have below nginx conf file

```
upstream entry {
    server 127.0.0.1:3001;
    }
    server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  127.0.0.1;

    location / {
        proxy_pass          http://entry/;
    }
```

Whenever I hit `http://127.0.0.1:80/`, it will be redirected to `127.0.0.1:3001`. In the same way if I hit `http://127.0.0.1:3001/` it should be redirected to nginx server.
 
Any help on this will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If I am getting it correct you want `http://127.0.0.1:3001/` (node http server) to redirect to `http://127.0.0.1:80/` (nginx), which in turn will redirect to `http://127.0.0.1:3001/` (node http server). Why on earth you want to do that? You can use [node proxy module](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) to do that if you want to fall inside a infinite for loop.

But generally, sane people will will use nginx as reverse proxy (80->3001). And block port 3001 for any outside communication through firewall.

Comment: I think you didnt understand my requirement. In a very simple way I say is I dont want any direct access to http://127.0.0.1:3001/. All the request should be redirected to nginx server.

Comment: You can block any incoming traffic to port 3001 trough firewall. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/iptables-block-port/ this should help

Comment: Thanks. It will be helpful.